# Custom Memory Allocator Example (Need some clarification)

Tags: c++, memory-management

Just running through this example of a custom memory allocator header file and I was just wanting to understand some of the written code better.

```
class Allocator
{
public:
    Allocator(size_t size, void* start)
    {
        _start          = start;
        _size           = size;

        _used_memory     = 0;
        _num_allocations = 0;
    }

    virtual ~Allocator()
    {
        ASSERT(_num_allocations == 0 && _used_memory == 0);

        _start = nullptr;
        _size   = 0;
    }

    virtual void* allocate(size_t size, u8 alignment = 4) = 0;

    virtual void deallocate(void* p) = 0;

    void* getStart() const
    {
        return _start;
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return _size;
    }

    size_t getUsedMemory() const
    {
        return _used_memory;
    }

    size_t getNumAllocations() const
    {
        return _num_allocations;
    }

protected:
    void*         _start;
    size_t        _size;

    size_t        _used_memory;
    size_t        _num_allocations;
};

namespace allocator
{
    template <class T> T* allocateNew(Allocator& allocator)
    {
        return new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T;
    }

    template <class T> T* allocateNew(Allocator& allocator, const T& t)
    {
        return new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T(t);
    }

    template<class T> void deallocateDelete(Allocator& allocator, T& object)
    {
        object.~T();
        allocator.deallocate(&object);
    }

    template<class T> T* allocateArray(Allocator& allocator, size_t length)
    {
        ASSERT(length != 0);

        u8 headerSize = sizeof(size_t)/sizeof(T);

        if(sizeof(size_t)%sizeof(T) > 0)
            headerSize += 1;

        //Allocate extra space to store array length in the bytes before the array
        T* p = ( (T*) allocator.allocate(sizeof(T)*(length + headerSize), __alignof(T)) ) + headerSize;

        *( ((size_t*)p) - 1 ) = length;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
            new (&p[i]) T;

        return p;
    }

    template<class T> void deallocateArray(Allocator& allocator, T* array)
    {
        ASSERT(array != nullptr);

        size_t length = *( ((size_t*)array) - 1 );

        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
            array[i].~T();

        //Calculate how much extra memory was allocated to store the length before the array
        u8 headerSize = sizeof(size_t)/sizeof(T);

        if(sizeof(size_t)%sizeof(T) > 0)
            headerSize += 1;

        allocator.deallocate(array - headerSize);
    }
};
```

1. Why is the start parameter needed/used here? If I wanted to allocate some space don't I just need to specify how much memory I need to allocate?
2. If I wanted to just create a simple linear custom memory allocater, would I still need to include the first two templates?
3. For this snippet `new (&p[i]) T;` why is the template type name at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) start stores the pointer to a "really" allocated memory that is being allocated by this allocator and later needs to be passed to corresponding free function.

2) i think it would be better to write your allocator from scratch

3) this expression is a placement new operator invocation and &p[i] is an address where an object of type T will be constructed